# opening the second window using undetected chromedriver + selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open two or more separate windows.

I was able to open the first window by running

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

drivers = list()
drivers.append(uc.Chrome(options=options))
```

Now I tried to open the second window by simply repeating the last line (`drivers.append(uc.Chrome(options=options))`), but it returned

```
RuntimeError: you cannot reuse the ChromeOptions object
```

So I tried

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

drivers.append(uc.Chrome(options=options))
```

This time it returned

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:54208
from chrome not reachable
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I just did it with undetected-chromedriver v1 , have a look and let me know if it works

Comment: I think, each time when you "create" Chrome driver you need also create a new options variable. It helped me, see [here](https://coder.social/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/555)

Comment: please check change log for version 3.1.0: https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me , I couldn't use v2 but it works in v1.

```
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc  
    uc.install(executable_path=PATH,)
    drivers_dict={}   
    def scraping_function(link):
            try:
                thread_name= threading.current_thread().name
                    #sometime we are going to have different thread name in each iteration so a little regex might help
                thread_name = re.sub("ThreadPoolExecutor-(\d*)_(\d*)", r"ThreadPoolExecutor-0_\2", thread_name)
                print(f"re.sub -> {thread_name}")
                driver = drivers_dict[thread_name]
            except KeyError:
                drivers_dict[threading.current_thread().name] = uc.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=PATH)
                driver = drivers_dict[threading.current_thread().name]
            driver.get(link)
```